# How to run PowerShell/PowerCli scripts on esxi 4?

Tags: powershell, vmware-esxi

I'm trying to use [the linked clones](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-9202) script for esxi 4, however I'm not sure how to run this script. I'm connecting to the esxi server with SSH and trying to run the scripts but it does nothing. Probably I need to open it with something that will process the script.

What I need to do? I need to install PowerCLI on the esxi server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

PowerCli runs on a Windows client machine. You connect to the ESX(i) box using the Connect-VIServer command:

```
Connect-VIServer –Server 1.2.3.4 –Protocol https –User username –Password password
```

Once you are connected then you can run all the PowerCli commands against the server you are connected to.

Answer (score 0):

PowerCLI is a snap-in for Microsoft Powershell. It connects to ESXi using the VMware Web Services API. To utilize PowerCLI and the API on ESXi hosts, you must have a licensed version of vSphere/ESXi.

Connecting is as simple as:

```
Connect-VIServer <ESXi IP or HOSTNAME> -credential (Get-Credential)
```